# IntelliJ IDEA + Gradleでexploded warのデプロイをする方法

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jboss

以下の環境でJavaEEアプリケーションを開発しています。

- Java8
- Gradle 4.10.3
- Wildfly 10
- Eclipse Oxygen から IntelliJ IDEA 2021.2(Ultimate)に乗り換えた

Eclipseでの開発では、Wildflyへデプロイ（Debug on server）すると、deploymentsフォルダに`hoge.war`フォルダが作られて、それがDeployment Scannerで拾われてデプロイされている模様でした。
静的ファイルを修正すると、Eclipseがdeploymentsフォルダに自動で再配置してくれるため、フロントエンドの開発がスムーズでした。

しかしIntelliJ IDEAに変えたところ、デプロイの方式が変わりました。
warファイルがビルドされ、Wildflyはそれを参照してデプロイしているようです。
どうやら、Deployment Scannerが使われていません。
IntelliJ IDEAのArtifacts to Deployの画面を見ると、

- `Gradle : hoge : hoge.war`
- `Gradle : hoge : hoge.war (exploded)`

の2つがあります。
これまで前者で試していましたが、調べてみると、どうも後者が私が望むもののようです。
しかしこれを試してみても、うまくいきません。
Wildflyのログには、 `java.io.FileNotFoundException: [当該プロジェクトのパス]\build\libs\exploded\hoge.war (指定されたパスが見つかりません。)` というエラーが出力されています。
確かにその位置にそんなファイル／フォルダは生成されていません。

恐らくこれが生成されていないのが原因だと思うのですが・・・
どうしたら解決できるでしょうか？